# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'single_product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<slug>)/$']

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

I got this error using django 2.2 here are my codes

### urls.py

app_name = 'products'

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', product_list, name='product-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$',single, name="single_product"),
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>.*)/$',category_single,name="category")
]
```

### views.py in product model

```
def get_absolute_url(self,):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('single_product',args=[self.slug]))
```

### tempplate

```
<h3>{{ product }}</h3>
<p>{{ product.description }}</p>
<p>{{ product.get_price }}</p>
<p>
   <a href ="{% url 'products:single_product' %}" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
      View Product
   </a>
```

Comment: Your hyperlink must be sent an argument to 'products:single_product', in the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are not passing the slug in the url but have given a parameter to your pattern.

so change the html

```
<a href ="{% url 'products:single_product' product.slug %}" class = "btn btn-primary" role = "button">
      View Product
   </a>
```